# Git command to commit to remote branch

Tags: git

I created a branch in my local machine then staged after making change to change.html

```
git checkout -b myBranch //create a branch in my local machine
git add change.html
```

then I created a branch in github page, called "fix/remoteRepo".
then I did following to create a short name for the remote URL repo.

```
git remote add haeminsh https://github.com/mywork/fix/haeminish
```

then to commit change.html to the remote repo,

```
git push myBranch haeminish
```

I am getting following error:

```
fatal: 'myBranch' does not appear to be a git repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What is the problem? I do not want to make any changes to the master but to my remote repo.

---

How do I find a correct URL?

Comment: your remote is named haeminsh, so you should probably be doing something more like git push haeminsh myBranch

Comment: also what is "danielle"?

Comment: I did "git push haeminish myBranch" and getting "fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mywork/fix/haeminsh' not found"

Comment: Tracking Branches : https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html Check this out.

Comment: haeminish, I might be wrong, but github's repository URLs are not in that format...how did you come up with github.com/mywork/fix/haeminsh?  don't they usually have your username and repo name followed by .git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run: `git push <remote> <branch>`. Here your remote name is `haeminish` and branch name `myBranch`.

First remove current remote `haeminish` then, add `haeminish` with correct URL.

```
$ git remote rm haeminish        # remove remote haeminish

$ git remote add haeminish https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git  # add new 'haeminish' with correct url
# replace <username> & <reponame> with exact value

$ git push haeminish myBranch
```

Comment: I did and got this error "fatal: repository 'github.com/mywork/fix/haeminsh'; not found"

Comment: if the address of the remote repo is https://github.com/mywork/tree/fix/haeminish, do I still add do "git remote add haeminish https://github.com/mywork"?

Comment: where can I find the URL? is it same as URL of the branch page on github?

Comment: URL should be https://github.com/mywork/<username>/<reponame>. Page not found for `github.com/mywork/tree/fix/haeminish`!!

Comment: @haeminish, what does that mean?

Comment: Just copy your `repo's https clone url`.

Comment: @sajibkhan repo for master is https://github.com/masterproject/ and my branch is https://github.com/masterproject/fix/haeminish. which one is the <reponame>?

Comment: I guess `masterproject` is GitHub username. What is your repositories clone url?